# Can Umbraco function as a full fledge CMS system

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I would like ourside users to post videos, articles, audio, links and images. The users should be able to post the content then I approve or decline the content based on my own criteria. Users should be able to up/down vote articles, post comments and vote on the the comments. When someone views an article they should be able to see similar posts. Also, since umbraco uses xslt will my site be able to scale?

I understand that there might be alot of programming invloved but if the site will scale well i am willing to use it.

Comment: @Luke101 I used Umbraco a few years back. I found it to be OpenSource in name, but commercial in venture. Meaning, good docs were hard to be found, but you could pay (alot) for support. This may have all changed, but it was my impression at the time. Also, I wonder if you what you are wanting is more of a "community management" system than a "content management system". The difference in my mind is that a CMS normally has a limited number of trusted users.

Comment: I don't see that using xslt would prevent scaling? 
Umbraco -is- a fully fledged CMS system :) Many of the features you mention are not core CMS functions.

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco is a full-fledged CMS system.  Although it sounds like you are asking if it can handle user generated content.  So maybe you mean a Community Management System?

Umbraco does have member management and through the Umbraco API you can allow for image uploads, video embeds, etc.  Or you could build your own database and use .NET User Controls to create / read content from that custom database.

All XSLT is cached so speed is generally not an issue, but you could use User Controls if you see some slowdown (would have to be LOTS of content).

If you are a .NET programmer, then Umbraco is a great option.  If not, then just using XSLT to build a community management system might be daunting.